# VBA replacement - syntax error?

Tags: vba, excel, replace, syntax

I am trying to do a repacement function in VBA.
Clearly I have some syntax problem, rookie that I am. 
my current approach:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 100

   Rows("i:i").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="i.xlsx", Replacement:="i+1.xlsx", LookAt:=xlPart _
        , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

Next i
```

Can anyone help me to correct the syntax for i ? Also instead of 100 lines, i would like to loop until end of file, how can I do that?

Thankful for help

Comment: You need to concatenate strings.

Comment: You are going to want to step backwards in that For ... Next. As it is it looks like you want to change 1.xlsx to 2.xlsx then in the next loop change 2.xlsx to 3.xlsx.

Comment: @Jeeped wouldn't that depend on whether `Rows("i:i")` also means to be referring to the `i` loop counter variable?

Comment: FWIW you should declare `i As Long`. Otherwise you'll inevitably encounter integer overflow when you start dealing with row numbers greater than 32,767.

Answer (score 3):

`"i"` is a *string literal*; as such, its value is constant throughout execution of the loop: it will always be `"i"`, regardless of the value of `i`.

If you want the variable `i` as part of the search/replacement string (e.g. `12.xlsx`), then you need to concatenate its string representation; `What:=i & ".xlsx"` and `Replacement:=i + 1 & ".xlsx"`.

Avoiding the very frail `.Select` instruction is rather easy, too. Work with the range you're interested in, rather than working with `Selection`.

```
Rows("i:i").Replace ...
```

Or did you mean `"i:i"` to also be your loop counter? Because `Range("I:I")` points to *column* I. If you meant to do `Rows("12:12")` at the 12th iteration, then you need to concatenate the range address there too:

```
Rows(i & ":" & i).Replace ...
```

If that's not the case then you'll want to heed [@Jeeped's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013556/vba-replacement-syntax-error/49013700#comment85032109_49013556) regarding the state of your values as the loop progresses.

Comment: Thanks for your advice: here is the macro i recorded and am trying to adapt now:      `Rows("05:05").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="01.xlsx", Replacement:="02.xlsx", LookAt:=xlPart _
        , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Rows("06:06").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="01.xlsx", Replacement:="03.xlsx", `...